# Merge dfs in a dictionary based on a column key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, merge

I have a dictionary like so: {key_1: pd.Dataframe, key_2: pd.Dataframe, ...}.

Each of these dfs within the dictionary has a column called 'ID'.

Not all instances appear in each dataframe meaning that the dataframes are of different size.

Is there anyway I could combine these into one large dataframe?

Here's a minimal reproducible example of the data:

```
data1 = [{'ID': 's1', 'country': 'Micronesia', 'Participants':3},
        {'ID':'s2', 'country': 'Thailand', 'Participants': 90},
        {'ID':'s3', 'country': 'China', 'Participants': 36},
        {'ID':'s4', 'country': 'Peru', 'Participants': 30}]
 

data2 = [{'ID': '1', 'country': 'Micronesia', 'Kids_per_participant':3},
        {'ID':'s2', 'country': 'Thailand', 'Kids_per_participant': 9},
        {'ID':'s3', 'country': 'China', 'Kids_per_participant': 39}]


data3= [{'ID': 's1', 'country': 'Micronesia', 'hair_style_rank':3},
        {'ID':'s2', 'country': 'Thailand', 'hair_style_rank': 9}]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)  
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data3)

dict_example={'df1_key':df1,'df2_key':df2,'df3_key':df3}

pd.merge(dict_example.values(), on="ID", how="outer")
```

Comment: Thanks!  @EoinS's answer does it for me. I edited my question only to create a clearer example of dataset variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a `dict` with arbitrary number of keys you could do this

```
i=list(dict_example.keys())
newthing = dict_example[i[0]]
for j in range(1,len(i)):
  newthing = newthing.merge(dict_example[i[j]],on='ID', how = 'outer')
```

First make a list of your dataframes.  Second create a `first` DataFrame.  Then iterate through the rest of your DataFrames and `merge` each one after that.  I did notice you have `country` for each `ID`, but it's not listing in your initial `on` statement.  Do you want to join on `country` also?  If so replace the merge above with this changing the join criteria to a list including `country`

```
newthing = newthing.merge(dict_example[i[j]],on=['ID','country'], how = 'outer')
```

[Documents](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) on `merge`

If you don't care about altering your DataFrames code could be shorter like this

```
for j in range(1,len(i)):
  df1 = df1.merge(dict_example[i[j]],on=['ID','country'], how = 'outer')
```